# Unity using dll gives TypeLoadException: Could not load file or assembly PresentationCore

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll

I've written an extremely simple dll to figure out how it works. But I'm getting that ugly error.
The source of the dll is

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TTiles
{
    public class Class1
    {
        private const int DefaultExtent = 4096;

        public static int GetNumber()
        {
            return 5;
        }

        public static async Task<int> GetNumberAsync()
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.4));

            return 5;
        }
    }
}
```

And the Unity script is basically just

```
using System;
using Mapbox.Platform;
using TTiles;

namespace Assets.Scripts.Cache
{
internal class TRequest : IAsyncRequest
{
    #region External Headers - We don't need them!
/*
    [DllImport("TTiles")]
    private static extern Task<Byte[]> GetTileAsync();

    [DllImport("TTiles")]
    private static extern int GetNumber();
*/
    #endregion



    #region Constructor

    public TRequest(Action<Response> callback, int timeout)
    {
        IsCompleted = false;
        _callback = callback;
        _timeout = timeout;

        GetVectorNumberAsync();
    }

    #endregion


    #region Private Methods

    private async void GetVectorNumberAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var number = await Class1.GetNumberAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(number);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }

        IsCompleted = true;
    }


    #endregion

}
}
```

The dll is compiled as x64 in Visual Studio (because Unity is 64bit).
The dll has been copied into the Assets\Plugins\ folder (automatically after every build).
Unity isn't complaining about any compilation problems...

There is no `PresentationCore` reference in the source dll - it isn't required.
I have tried adding it (v4.0.0.0), but it makes no difference.

I have enabled **Experimental (.NET 4.6 Equivalent)** in Unity.
The dll is built with .NET 4.6.

But I get this error on run.

> TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 'A.cb56c87025be887e2687073fa009b1198:c8f44f8494ce26970d56fa7d1f7c06e04' (1) due to: Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationCore, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. assembly:presentationCore, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 type: member:
>   System.RuntimeType.GetMethodsByName (System.String name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Boolean ignoreCase, System.RuntimeType reflectedType) (at :0)
>   System.RuntimeType.GetMethodCandidates (System.String name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.CallingConventions callConv, System.Type[] types, System.Boolean allowPrefixLookup) (at :0)
>   System.RuntimeType.GetMethods (System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr) (at :0)
>   UnityEditor.Build.BuildPipelineInterfaces.InitializeBuildCallbacks (UnityEditor.Build.BuildPipelineInterfaces+BuildCallbacks findFlags) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildPipelineInterfaces.cs:188)

What am I doing wrong?
What do I need to do?

Comment: Do you have a reference to PresentationCore in the project of the source dll?

Comment: @Crowcoder: I can add PresentationCore **v4.0.0.0**, not 3.0.0.0. It makes zero difference. Visual Studio doesn't think it's necessary - I'm not doing any rendering, or anything visual.

Comment: I didn't mean you should add it. I doubt that would work in Unity. I was going to suggest you remove it.

Comment: I have doubts that error is because of the code you have shown.

Comment: Are you positive it is your DLL that is requiring it and not Mapbox?